# SQL total hours from varchar column

Tags: sql, time, sql-server-2016

I can't seem to find out how to get the total number of hours from `varchar` column from SQL Server 2016.

Query:

```
SELECT taakuren
FROM taken
```

Returns

```
10:00     
12:15    
26:00     
40:00
```

I would like it to return

```
88:15
```

I've tried things like below query but a always end up with issue when it gets past 24 hours

```
select Convert(Varchar, (Convert(DateTime, taakuren)), 114) as TotalTime 
from taken
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the `time` data type peters out at 24 hours.  If you want more hours, then you may have to resort to your own arithmetic:

```
select cast(sum(hours * 60 + minutes) / 60 as varchar(10)) + ':' +
       right('00' + cast(sum(hours * 60 + minutes) % 60 as varchar(10)))
from taken t outer apply
     (values (left(t.taakuren, 2) + 0, right(t.taakuren, 2) + 0)
     ) v(hours, minutes);
```

Comment: Dang! Now that's fast. By the time I created a test case, you had an answer with a working example! It's great to learn from you.

Comment: awesome!! that fast your good :) only get total hours now 88:0.

Answer (score 0):

update my code is:

```
select cast(sum(hours * 60 + minutes) / 60 as varchar(10)) + ':' +
   cast(sum(hours * 60 + minutes) % 60 as varchar(10))
from taken t outer apply
 (values (left(t.taakuren, 2) + 0, SUBSTRING(t.taakuren, 4,6) + 0)
 ) v(hours, minutes)
```